# headers for more than one line

Tags: email, mime

How can I read header from mail? Is there regex to do it? I have especially problem with headers like these:

```
From: John Doe <example@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="XXXXboundary text"
```

What is the space before boundary? Is it tab or what?

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt page 19

Answer (score 2):

What language?

I recommend perl for this task.  Visit cpan.org and get MIME::Tools if your perl installation doesn't come with those modules.